# Is my Non-Contact Voltage Tester from Klein Tools safe?

Tags: safety, tools, recalls

There are many questions regarding Non-Contact Voltage Testers. They are a great safety tool when used as recommended and when they are functioning as designed.

Has mine been recalled?

Model: Klein Tools NCVT-1
Date code: 1119C-G8

Answer (score 14):

US Consumer Product Safety Commission announced a [recall of select Klein Tools NCVT-1 voltage testers](https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2021/Non-Contact-Voltage-Testers-Recalled-by-Klein-Tools-Due-to-Shock-Hazard).

These were sold individually and as part of kits. I have one, but the recall is **only for date code ending in H7**. So I'm OK (code ends in G8).

> **Hazard:** The on/off button can remain depressed during the power on or power off cycle, causing the tester to work improperly. Consumers testing electrical sources could fail to be warned of the presence of live voltage if the tester is not properly operating, posing a shock hazard to the users.

Full details at the link above. Safety first!

Comment: For the time if/when the link dies, would you mind indicating what part of the tester is _un_ safe? i.e. is it failing to detect electricity in live wires, or does it provide a shock risk to the user, or is the tip small enough that people are using it as a nose pick and injuring themselves, or...?

Comment: My tester has date code G6, so I guess it is OK. Regardless, after turning it on, I always do a test against a known live conductor before wandering into the jungle of unknown wires.

Comment: @JohnCanon, proper procedure is "known live, unknown, known live".  This protects against things like the battery dying just after you test the known-live wire.